# Swig : How to typemap two fields of a struct?

Tags: c++, swig

I'm using Swig to wrap a C/C++ into Java.

I have this structure :

```
struct score {
    void* goals;
    uint32_t goals_number; 
}
```

I need to make the parity between goals and goals_number.

this kind of typemap works for me only in case of a function arguments parity :

```
%apply (unsigned int *OUTPUT, size_t LENGTH) { (void* goals, uint32_t goals_number) };
```

What about applying the parity on a structure fields? How to do it?

Thank you a lot!

**EDIT** :

I need to get the signature of the getter and setter at this way in the Java side :

```
public class Score {

    // ... other methods

    void setGoals( int goals[] ){
        //...
    }

    int[] getGoals(){
        //...
        // goals.length must be equal to "goals_number"
    }
}
```

Instead of :

```
  public void setGoals(SWIGTYPE_p_void value) {
    MyModuleJNI.Score_goals_set(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_void.getCPtr(value));
  }

  public SWIGTYPE_p_void getGoals() {
    long cPtr = MyModuleJNI.Score_goals_get(swigCPtr, this);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_void(cPtr, false);
  }

  public void setGoals_number(long value) {
    MyModuleJNI.Score_goals_number_set(swigCPtr, this, value);
  }

  public long getGoals_number() {
    return MyModuleJNI.Score_goals_number_get(swigCPtr, this);
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call a function that accepts a `score` instead of a `(int*, size_t)`?

Comment: I need it to get the right getters and setters.

Comment: Please give example code of what you mean by "applying the parity on a structure fields", what would the java code that uses this look like?

Comment: @Schollii, thank you, I did an edit.

Comment: it should work, can you be more specific about what doesn't work? And can you confirm that you mean `setGoals(score goals[])` or do you really mean an array of ints?

Comment: @Schollii,Hello sir , I really mean an array of int. thank you

Comment: @Schollii I have done an edit

Answer (score 0):

Try the `%extend` directive:

```
// score.i:
%{
#include "Score.h"
%}

%include "Score.h"

%extend Score  %{
    void setGoals( int goals[] ){
        //... use $self->goals_number and $self->goals to populate
        // goals array
    }

    int* getGoals(){
        //...
        int* swigGoals = new int[$self->goals_number]; 
        // populate swigGoals, then
        return swigGoals; 
    }
%}
```

You might have to massage that a bit if you want to be able to modify the array returned.

You might want to hide the two public attributes so they are not visible from Java (using `%ignore Score::goals` etc).

Comment: Thank u sir for the try, but the matter is that I should not populate the array inside the getter. I guess it should be kind of typemap. But only a guessing

Comment: @GotACrushOnIT it is very likely that the typemap code will do exactly that (copy the array).